WooCommerce plugin for coupons
I am making a WordPress plugin that works with WooCommerce. I have a database table with discount codes. With this code my customer can buy 10 tickets for a movie. This could mean he orders 10 tickets in a single order, or five orders with two tickets each.
// CHECK IF COUPON CODE EXISTS
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'check_coupon_code', 10, 2);

function check_coupon_code($valid, $coupon) {
    
    error_log('HERE I AM!');
    
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'strippenkaarten';
    
    // GET COUPON CODE
    $coupon_code = $coupon->get_code();
    
    error_log('COUPON CODE: ' . $coupon_code);
    
    // CHECK IF EXISTS
    $strippenkaart = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE coupon_code = %s",
        $coupon_code
    ));
    
    // DOES NOT EXIST OR NO REMAINING TICKETS
    if (!$strippenkaart || $strippenkaart->remaining_tickets <= 0) {
        return false; // Coupon is invalid
    }

    return true; // Coupon is valid
}

I have to manually check if the coupon code entered by the customer exists in my table strippenkaarten. I added a error-log at the start of my function, but I never see it in my logs. Logs is working, because I do see other logs I put in my plugin.
Why is my function never called?

I need the coupon code, filled at the WooCommerce checkout. But the POST data is empty. Not a single thing is in the POST data. How can I get the coupon code when I add the coupon

I use checkout blocks. As mentioned in my question, I have a database table with coupon codes. Each coupon has x ticket remaining, that a customer can buy. When a coupon code is entered and clicked on apply, I want to manually check if the coupon code is in MY database table. If yes, apply the discount.

The problem with checkout Blocks is that it uses React, so you will not be able to catch anything with $_POST or even JavaScript Ajax… WooCommerce Cart or/and Checkout Blocks only allow very few customizations, and some of them are quite complicated to implement.

Maybe you could try to use the filter hook woocommerce_coupon_is_valid located in WC_Discount is_coupon_valid() method

In your handler for that hook, there won’t be POST data to use. WordPress and WooCommerce handle form posts in an idiosyncratic way. What data do you need here?

I am using woocommerce_coupon_is_valid now, but my function is never called.
